# Adding String Value Converted From YAML File To PowerShell Array As An Object

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a YAML config file that I read values from and is structured as below:

```
hosts:
  - name: server1
    role: 
      - role1
    services:
      - iis
      - sql
  - name: server2
    role: 
      - role1
      - role4
    services:
      - iis
  - name: server3
    role:
      - role2
    services:
      - sql_server
```

And I read from this YAML config file in a PowerShell script and store the config in a variable called `$config`

I created empty arrays to then iterate through the list of hosts and store in the corresponding array based on a role as below:

```
$role1_servers,$role2_servers = @()
$config.hosts |  % {
    $server_name = $_.name
    $_.role | % {
        switch($_){
            "role1" {
                $role1_servers+= $server_name
            }
            "role2" {
                $role2_servers+= $server_name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But instead of adding the values to the relevant array, PowerShell is doing string concatenation rather than adding an item to the array.

When outputting `$role1_servers` for example, it would output

```
server1server2
```

rather than the desired output of

```
server1
server2
```

Is there a way to add the string value as an object to the array rather than string concatenation? I'd need these items in an array to iterate through all servers in a particular role at a later stage.

Comment: Looks like you already have parsed the yaml file into objects?

Comment: @Theo - yes, just looking to add the server name as an object into the array rather than a literal string

Comment: Then can't you simply do `$config.hosts | Select-Object @{Name = 'Server'; Expression = {$_.name}}, @{Name = 'Role'; Expression = {$_.role}}` ? (or do some servers have multiple roles)

Comment: Yes, sorry, some servers have multiple roles. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from our comments, I think the best thing to do is to create an object array where all server names and roles are present like this:

```
$allServers = $config.hosts | ForEach-Object {
    $server = $_.name
    foreach ($role in $_.role) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Server = $server
            Role   = $role
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can filter out all servers having a certain role

```
$role1_servers = $allServers | Where-Object { $_.role -eq 'role1' }
$role2_servers = $allServers | Where-Object { $_.role -eq 'role2' }

# etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a ready made module from [PS Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) for handling YAML.

```
install-module powershell-yaml

$hosts = @'
hosts:
  - name: server1
    role: 
      - role1
    services:
      - iis
      - sql
  - name: server2
    role: 
      - role1
      - role4
    services:
      - iis
  - name: server3
    role:
      - role2
    services:
      - sql_server
'@ | ConvertFrom-Yaml | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now you can filter the values you are looking for

```
$hosts.hosts | where role -like '*role1*'

name    services role
----    -------- ----
server1 iis sql  role1
server2 iis      role1 role4
```

Comment: I use the double convert through Json to pivot the data structure as I think that makes it more readable.